# Need to read XML c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need to read the following XML docuemt and save all the fields in variables to use later on.
Tried Linq but do't really understand how o use it.
I need help, what code should I write to read the XML and save the fields in variables?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Map name="Mapa Prueba" width="30" height="30" hp="500" orobyte="50" Tx="1" Ty="5" Sx="30" Sy="25"  >

    <StructuresList>
        <Structure name="Block de Notas" attack="0" i="1" j="1" range="0" price="8" />
        <Structure name="Excel" attack="2" i="2" j="2" range="1" price="20" />
        <Structure name="Word" attack="3" i="2" j="2" range="1" price="40" />
        <Structure name="PowerPoint" attack="3" i="3" j="2" range="1" price="50" />
        <Structure name="FireWall" attack="1" i="1" j="1" range="1" price="60" />
        <Structure name="Avast" attack="4" i="3" j="3" range="2" price="80" />
        <Structure name="Nod32" attack="4" i="3" j="2" range="2" price="110" />
        <Structure name="Panda" attack="6" i="3" j="2" range="1" price="130" />
        <Structure name="Norton" attack="5" i="3" j="3" range="2" price="150" />
        <Structure name="Eclipse" attack="4" i="3" j="4" range="3" price="180" />
        <Structure name="Visual Studio" attack="10" i="5" j="6" range="1" price="200" />
    </StructuresList>

    <EnemysList>
        <Enemy id="00" color="rojo" hp="20" orobyte="1" speed="1" />
        <Enemy id="01" color="azul" hp="10" orobyte="1" speed="2" />
        <Enemy id="02" color="amarillo" hp="35" orobyte="3" speed="1" />
        <Enemy id="03" color="celeste" hp="30" orobyte="2" speed="2" />
        <Enemy id="04" color="azul" hp="10" orobyte="1" speed="4" />
        <Enemy id="05" color="rojo" hp="60" orobyte="3" speed="1" />
        <Enemy id="06" color="celeste" hp="100" orobyte="10" speed="1" />
        <Enemy id="07" color="amarillo" hp="150" orobyte="25" speed="3" />
        <Enemy id="08" color="verde" hp="200" orobyte="40" speed="5" />
    </EnemysList>

    <Waves>
        <Wave>
            <Group id="00" count="10" />
            <Group id="01" count="5" />
        </Wave>
        <Wave>
            <Group id="00" count="15" />
            <Group id="01" count="5" />
        </Wave>
        <Wave>
            <Group id="01" count="25" />
        </Wave>
        <Wave>
            <Group id="00" count="24" />
            <Group id="01" count="5" />
        </Wave>
        <Wave>
            <Group id="02" count="20" />
        </Wave>
        <Wave>
            <Group id="02" count="10" />
            <Group id="03" count="20" />
        </Wave>
        <Wave>
            <Group id="03" count="20" />
            <Group id="07" count="1" />
        </Wave>
        <Wave>
            <Group id="03" count="10" />
            <Group id="04" count="30" />
        </Wave>
        <Wave>
            <Group id="05" count="30" />
            <Group id="06" count="10" />
            <Group id="07" count="1" />
        </Wave>
        <Wave>
            <Group id="08" count="3" />
        </Wave>
    </Waves>

</Map>
```

Comment: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/threads/321453/read-xml-then-put-into-variables google your best friend :)

Comment: Please don't include tags in question titles.

Comment: "I need to read ..." - permission granted, go ahead and do that, "what code should I write" - you should write correct, readable code. Now if you have more specific questions (i.e. "why my following {sample code} LINQ code does return XXXX instead of YYYY") you question will be much better fir for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path =@"file.xml";

            Map mymap = new Map();
            var xml = XDocument.Load(path);
            var map = xml.Descendants("Map").Select(x => new Map()
                {
                    Structures = x.Element("StructuresList").Elements("Structure").Select(r => new StructuresList()
                    {
                        Name = r.Attribute("name").Value,
                        Attack =Convert.ToInt32(r.Attribute("attack").Value),
                        I = Convert.ToInt32(r.Attribute("i").Value),
                        J = Convert.ToInt32(r.Attribute("j").Value),
                        Range = Convert.ToInt32(r.Attribute("range").Value),
                        Price = Convert.ToInt32(r.Attribute("price").Value)

                    }).ToList(),

                    Enemys = x.Element("EnemysList").Elements("Enemy").Select(r => new EnemysList()
                    {
                        ID = Convert.ToInt32(r.Attribute("id").Value),
                        Color = r.Attribute("color").Value.ToString(),
                        HP = Convert.ToInt32(r.Attribute("hp").Value),
                        Orobyte = Convert.ToInt32(r.Attribute("orobyte").Value),
                        Speed = Convert.ToInt32(r.Attribute("speed").Value)
                    }).ToList(),

                    Waves = x.Element("Waves").Elements("Wave").Select(y => new Wave()
                    {
                        Groups = y.Elements("Group").Select(r => new Group()
                        {
                            ID = Convert.ToInt32(r.Attribute("id").Value),
                            Count = Convert.ToInt32(r.Attribute("count").Value)
                        }).ToList()
                    }).ToList()
                }).First();
           }


        internal class Map
        {
            public List<StructuresList> Structures { set; get; }

            public List<EnemysList> Enemys { set; get; }

            public List<Wave> Waves { set; get; }
        }

        internal class StructuresList
        { 
            public string Name{set;get;}

            public int Attack { set; get; }

            public int I { set; get; }

            public int J { set; get; }

            public int Range { set; get; }

            public int Price { set; get; }
        }

        internal class EnemysList
        {

            public int ID { set; get; }
            public string Color { set; get; }
            public int HP { set; get; }

            public int  Orobyte { set; get; }
            public int Speed { set; get; }

        }

        internal class Wave
        {
            public int WaveID { set; get; }
            public List<Group> Groups { set; get; }
        }

        internal class Group
        {
            public int ID { set; get; }

            public int Count { set; get; }
        }
```

To print data out

```
             Console.WriteLine("Strucrures"); 
                foreach (var str in map.Structures)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name :{0}  , Attack:{1}  , I:{2}  , J:{3}  ,  Range:{4}  ,  Price:{5}"
                        , str.Name, str.Attack, str.I, str.J, str.Range, str.Price);
                }


                Console.WriteLine("Enemys");
                foreach (var enmy in map.Enemys)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ID :{0}  , Color:{1}  , HP:{2}  , Orobyte:{3}  ,  Speed:{4} "
                        , enmy.ID, enmy.Color, enmy.HP, enmy.Orobyte, enmy.Speed);
                }


                Console.WriteLine("Waves");

                 foreach (var enmy in map.Waves)
                 {
                    Console.WriteLine("Wave ID:{0}", enmy.WaveID);
                    foreach(var gr in enmy.Groups)
                    Console.WriteLine("ID :{0}  , Count:{1} "
                        , gr.ID, gr.Count);
                  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take your pick of any of these already answered versions of your same question.

[LINQ to read XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml)

[Reading an XML using libxml2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741221/reading-an-xml-using-libxml2)

[Reading Xml with XmlReader in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441673/reading-xml-with-xmlreader-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `linq` this is a basic example. For instance with this piece of code you will be retrieving all the `Structure` in `StructureList` and checking the attributes. It's quite easy, you will get an idea.

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile); //Or XDocument.Parse(xmlString)

var structures = xDoc.Descendants("StructuresList").Descendants("Structure")
                     .ToList();

foreach (var structure in structures)
{
    var name = structure.Attribute("name").Value;
    var attack = structure.Attribute("attack").Value;
    //Continue checking attributes
}
```